# Как убрать Padding элемента если он находится в col-

Tags: html, css3, bootstrap, flexbox

У меня есть вот такой код:

```
<div class="my-flex-block-featured_products col-lg-2 test_padding">
    <img src="src/img/small_lot.png">
</div>
<div class="my-flex-block-featured_products2 col-lg-2 test_padding" align="left">
    <button class="small__description">SHOE EXAMPLE SIZE L</button>
    <button class="small__price">$39.8911111</button>
    <button class="small__cart">
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-2x"></i>
    <span class="slide_btn">
    </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

На практике это отображается вот так : 
[image]
[image]

Каким образом можно убрать этот padding если я уже прописал в test_padding :
padding: 0 0 0 0;

Comment: посмотрите в devTools, какие стили его перебивают. и вопрос - как вы прописали в test_padding? вы понимаете приоритетность стилей? вы достаточно подняли приоритет своих стиле по сравнению с теми, которые установили не нужный вам паддинг?

Comment: может вес селектора .test_padding ниже, и из-за этого не работает

Comment: Пропишите таким образом:
`.test_padding {
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}`

Comment: @Maqsood ну чему вы людей учите... не разбираться, а костыли лепить.

Comment: Скиньте полный код и я вам помогу, не хочу додумывать.